# Impulse Response Values VAR Statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels, var

I am trying to understand how the values of the irf plots are estimated

I read following page:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html#impulse-response-analysis

But I don't understand how the values of the impulse response are estimated.

I have a model that I fit with order of 3.

```
result = model.fit(3)
```

coefficients and residuals:

```
result.summary()
```

irf values:

```
result.irf(3).irfs
```

At first, I thought the values of the coefficients are equal to the values of the irfs, but that only holds for the first lagged value 'L1'.
After that, the values of the irfs start to differ.

An example:

Imagine there are three variables in the system: `GDP, Sales, Export`, with order `3`

Results for equation Sales

```
L1.GDP = 1.37
L2.GDP = 1.63
L3.GDP = -0.69
```

Impulse responses:
GDP -> Sales

```
irf(t1): 1.37
irf(t2): 1.31
irf(t3): -7.62
```

How do I obtain the values at `t2` and `t3`?

From the docs:

```
Impulse responses are of interest in econometric studies: they are the estimated responses to a unit impulse in one of the variables. They are computed in practice using the MA representation of the VAR(p) process:
```

[image]